# How to done the scrollRight without animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to scroll the div tag in the right side but this is not worked. But the scroll left function and scroll right with animation is perfectly works. But i want to scroll right without animation I tried code something like this

```
$().ready(function(){
$("#container").scrollLeft(500); //This works
return hus;
});
function hus(){
$("#container").scrollLeft(-200); //This is not work
}
```

But i want to scroll the right side **without animation** how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean about "scroll right".

`$("#container").scrollLeft(500)`
scroll the div to the x-position of 500px (This works)

`$("#container").scrollLeft(-200)` scroll the div to the x-position of -200px, this is not a valid position since the minimum value is 0px, this is the left-most position, and you can't expect that it will "float" to the right side like a circle loop

`scrollLeft: leftPos - 800` doesn't "scroll right" as you thing, it scroll the div element to the left, too

So, as I guest, there are 2 posible case that match your problem
Let's begin with:

```
var leftPos = $('#container').scrollLeft();
```

We suppose that:

- `leftPos = 1000`, this is current x-position of the div
- `scrollWidth = 10000`, obtain from `$('#container')[0].scrollWidth`
- `width = 500`, obtain from `$('#container').width()`

If you want to move 200px to the right from current position, that is `1200`, you can use:

```
$("#container").scrollLeft(leftPos + 200);
```

If you want to move to the right position that is "200px away" from the right side, that is `10000-500-200`, you can use:

```
$("#container").scrollLeft(scrollWidth - width - 200);
```

Hope this can solve your problem. (Sorry, my grammar is not very well)

Comment: Can you tell why '$("#container").scrollLeft("#to-element-id");' didn't work? If I setting numbered value it works perfectly, but not when I tried to use element id to scroll to

Comment: @AndrewK, from the jQuery document (https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/), it seem that the function `.scrollLeft( value )` only take parameter `value` as `An integer indicating the new position to set the scroll bar to`, not the id string of element

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try: `$('#to-element-id')[0].scrollIntoView();`

Comment: I thought scrollLeft is the similar to srollTop which is has no problem to scroll to element ID, ok, thanks anyway! @phibao37

Answer (score 0):

You can set a duration of 0 or 1 ms which would do the trick:

```
var leftPos = $('#container').scrollLeft();
$("#container").animate({
   scrollLeft: leftPos - 800
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

An element is set to the left side by defaults. In this sense, there's no way you can scroll the element "in the right side" (a.k.a. to the left) at the very beginning.

In your case:

```
 1. $("#container").scrollLeft(500); //This works
```

This would work because you just move the element to the right side for 500px.

```
2. $("#container").scrollLeft(-200); //This is not work
```

This would not work since you are already on the left-most side, you are not able to scroll an element out of the outer box.

```
 3. var leftPos = $('#container').scrollLeft();
    $("#container").animate({
       scrollLeft: leftPos - 800
    }, 500);
    });
```

I am not sure what do you mean by "work perfectly" in this case, due to the lack of the context.

If what you want is to move the element "to the left" without animation, you may simply set `$('#container').scrollLeft('200');` 
(since you already set the element to scroll to right for 500px at the very beginning.)

You may check on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30j0ka4m/) for the example. If you want to turn off the animation effect, you can just set the duration to 0.